# Sublime Text - using backslash in Key Bindings

Tags: latex, sublimetext2

Switching from TextMate to Sublime Text I am trying to get my custom key bindings from one editor to the other.
Using LaTeX and being german I am using quite a few umlauts like äöü which the usual LaTeX installations can't compile. 
I would like to have a key binding which substitutes `ä` with `\"a`

Also this should only work while writing in a LaTeX file.

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this to apply only to your latex files, open the default sublime-keymap file for your build system and platform (Preferences, Browse packages, go to your LaTeX build-system).

In the file, add new key-bindings like

`{ 
    "keys": ["\\","\"","i"],
    "command": "insert",
    "args": {"characters": "ï"}
}`

In case you want the keys to be bind in every file you edit, then you can just copy these in the user keymap file (also in preferences).

Please pay special attention to the need to escape the backslash () and the quotation (") when defining the keys.